# Block Module jQuery Slider for Homepage

Tags: javascript, blocks

I have a simple jquery slider for the homepage of a website, which works in my static HTML/CSS layouts.

I want to incorporate this front-end mark-up into a block module that will allow an admin to add/edit/remove slides. Is there a good module that already does this that I could hack with to get this functionality. Or even better does anyone know a good tutorial (doesn't have to be for a slider), that shows developing a module where you can add/edit multiple items specific to that block module (separate to the main content); in my case it would be adding/editing slide items to the slider.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I follow what you are asking, mostly because I don't understand what you already do have.

Comment: I have a jquery slider in HTML/CSS, looking to create a block module that will allow edit and update of this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From reading your question, I take it you have zero integration with Drupal. You simply hardcode your entire slideshow in a block.

What I would suggest is that you start with creating a new content type, and then apply either [Field slideshow](http://drupal.org/project/field_slideshow) or [Views slideshow](http://drupal.org/project/views_slideshow) onto it.

> Provides a Slideshow formatter for Image fields, using JQuery Cycle plugin.
>
> Compared to Views slideshows, building the slideshow from multiple nodes, this module builds it from a single node, with a multi-valued Image/Media/Field Collection field.

> Views Slideshow can be used to create a slideshow of any content (not just images) that can appear in a View. Powered by jQuery, it is heavily customizable: you may choose slideshow settings for each View you create.

Answer (score 1):

To create a slider u need install this modules *(1) Views (2) Views UI (3) Views Slideshow (4) Views Slideshow: Cycle (5) Chaos tools (6) Link (7) Libraries (8) Token (Optional)*
First of all you need to create Image Cache with core module named **Image Styles** to resize your images for slider. Then u need to create new Content type with hidden comments and hidden author and date info. After this you will need to add some fields to this content type: 
**1) Image Field** with this settings

> ```
> (1) Label: Slider Image
> (2) Field: slider_image
> (3) Field type: image
> (4) Widget (form element): image
> (5) Click Save button, and on the field settings page leave default settings and click on Save field settings button.
> (6) On the image field configuration settings page you can configure as you wish.
> ```

2)Link Field:

> ```
> (1) Label: Slider Link
> (2) Field: slider_link
> (3) Field type: link
> (4) Widget (form element): link
> ```

Next you need to create content and upload there your images
After this you will need to create new View, where you can display your slider what ever you want.

Full tutorial you can find [HERE](http://www.brightwebsitedesign.com/how-to-install-views-slideshow-module-on-drupal7)